# Send multiple messages using google chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

I want to test message functionality in my browser game. Instead of sending messages manually to 50 test accounts I thought maybe I can do it automatically in Chrome console.

For first I would make a for loop.

```
 for (i=0; i > 50; i++)
    {

     //to do
    }
```

I would use my games link to fill the sending form 
*game.php?page=messages&mode=write&id=1&subject=message_test*
ID is for user ids and Subject fill the subject area.

In my message send template I use this JavaScript to send a message

```
function check(){
    if($('#text').val().length == 0) {
        alert('{$LNG.mg_empty_text}');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $.post('game.php?page=messages&mode=send&id={$id}&ajax=1', $('#message').serialize(), function(data) {
            alert(data);
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me how to execute a function using Chrome console and send out messages? Maybe put me to a proper tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to "export" your functions to the console into the google chrome or another dev tools, you can export it to a window object, so

```
// create a namespace to have all functions under your custom namespace
window.MyCustomNS = {};
window.MyCustomNS.yourFunction = function(id, dataObject) {
if($('#text').val().length == 0) {
    alert('{$LNG.mg_empty_text}');
    return false;
} else {
    $('submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $.post('game.php?page=messages&mode=send&id=' +  + '&ajax=1', $.param(dataObject), function(data) {
        alert(data);
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
        return true;
    });
}
};
```

then into the console you try this,

```
window.MyCustomNS.yourFunction('YOUR_ID', { name: 'some parameter', another: 'another parameter' });
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I enter input values there and submit so the message is sent?

Comment: You should program as the way you need your function, I mean your function need to keep the ajax logic into, then you can pass your input values as arguments for your function

Comment: @Thranduil In the place where it says: "your stuff here"... or maybe I am not understanding your question... can you please expand?

Comment: @ochi I don't get how to write a proper command there to enter the values and submit it. I am not good at java.

Comment: @Thranduil this is Javascript not Java, I will update my answer to better explanation to you

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez Thank you because I don't get it at all, i know basic programming, but its hard to understand how to make functions so it affect the website

Comment: Give me some time, my laptop is battery ofi right now :/, is charging now, but you need a function to insert valúes into a form into the web ? Or just a function that can pass arguments to be sent to your server?

Comment: Take your time. What I need is the same thing what you would do to send out a regular message, you click write a message, fill the subject area and enter text, then press send. I need to do this in my game using chrome console or firefox console. I can explain better using skype.

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez I figure out how to done that much easier